# Why this buffer array is 1 sample less the actual signal

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, splice

I am trying to create an arrray (buffer_array) in which I push 1 sample at a time and when it gets full I remove first 50% and fill again with new sample.

I am basically using a random number to generate the fakesignal. I plot this signal along with the buffer_array but after the first iteration buffer_array gets 1 sample less and signal and buffer looks totally different.

```
let  ring_buffer = [] 
let signal = []
let sampleLength = 20
let signalLength  = 0
let spacing = 16
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  signalLength = width/spacing
  
  //init signal
  // for(let i=0;i<signalLength;i++){
  //   signal.push(0)
  // }
  
  //init buffer
  // for(let i=0;i<sampleLength;i++){
  //   ring_buffer.push(0)
  // }
  
  frameRate(1)
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  translate(0,height>>2)
  
  // fake sensor signal sample
  let sample = 0<random(-30,30)?20:-20 
  
  //signal
  stroke(255,0,0)
  updateSignal(sample)
  drawSignal(signal,100)
  
  //ringbuffer
  stroke(0,0,255)
  updateRingbuffer(sample)
  drawSignal(ring_buffer,150)
  
  //draw axis
  drawAxis()
}

function updateSignal(sample){
  if(signal.length<signalLength){
    signal.push(sample)
  }else{
    signal.shift()
  }
}

function updateRingbuffer(sample){
  if(ring_buffer.length<sampleLength){
    ring_buffer.push(sample)
  }else{
    ring_buffer.splice(0,sampleLength/2) 
  }
}


function drawSignal(arr,offset){
  noFill()
  beginShape()
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    vertex(i*spacing,arr[i]+offset)
  }
  endShape()
}

function drawAxis(){
  fill(0)
  noStroke()
  textSize(8)
  textAlign(CENTER)
  for(let i=0;i<width;i+=spacing){ 
    text(i/spacing,i,200)
    push()
    translate(i,200)
    rotate(PI/2)
    stroke(0,10)
    line(-width/2,0,width/2,0)
    pop()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your expected behavior, but in any case I think you should `push` on the  arrays every time, even after you adjusted the length of the array by `shift` of `splice` ([skech](https://editor.p5js.org/kikon/sketches/FRywBpn3z))

Comment: @kikon can you try running the code or I can provide you a sketch. You can see the problem clearly  https://editor.p5js.org/black/sketches/-y3rHmSHa

Comment: Isn't this the code in your post? I hoped you can explain why my solution is not working for you.

Comment: And since you asked for an explanation, the explanation is that in your code since you don't add the `sample` to the signal whenever you `shift` the red signal and whenever you `splice` the second. However, except for the first time, *these events don't occur in the same step*, (the shift occurs every other step, while the splice every 10 steps) so you skip different items in the two arrays so they become rapidly unsynchronized (more precisely the current value is the same, but the previous one may not be the same). This is why you should not skip data, as in the code I provided before.

Comment: @Thank you.  I think I understood what you are trying to say .. but I think I fixed it my way - 

function updateSignal(sample){
  if(signal.length>signalLength-1){ 
    signal.shift()
  }
  signal.push(sample)
}

function updateRingbuffer(sample){
  if(ring_buffer.length>sampleLength-1){ 
    ring_buffer.splice(0,sampleLength/2) 
  }
  ring_buffer.push(sample)
}

Comment: You did exactly the same thing, all by yourself, congratulations! The main idea is to push the `sample` even in the case when the arrays are adjusted. The code in my sketch was obviously made to illustrate the concept with minimal modifications to yours.

Answer (score 0):

So as @kikon comment suggests that we need to push data in the array even when the array is getting adjust hence changing the updateSignal and updateRingbuffer as below will make sure of that -

```
function updateSignal(sample){
  if(signal.length>signalLength-1){ 
    signal.shift()
  }
  signal.push(sample)
}

function updateRingbuffer(sample){
  if(ring_buffer.length>sampleLength-1){ 
    ring_buffer.splice(0,sampleLength/2) 
  }
  ring_buffer.push(sample)
}
```